# watir-webdriver iterating table for field comparison

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

How can I iterate this table's rows and compare the value of each first column,
i.e 'Wallet1' == 'Wallet2' ?

And when the field has the same value, compare the 4th column value?

```
<table class="simple">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th class="labelCenter">Saldo</th>

        (...)

    </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="labelCenter">Wallet 1</td>
            <td class="labelCenter">Decresing</td>
            <td class="labelCenter">16/02/2012 19:06:01</td>
            <td class="labelCenter">19/02/2012 14:03:01</td>
                <td class="labelCenter">
                </td>       
            <td class="labelRight">
                    78,90
            </td>
                <td class="labelRight">
                    0,00
                </td>
            <td class="labelCenter">Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="labelCenter">Wallet 2</td>
        <td class="labelCenter">Increasing</td>
        <td class="labelCenter">16/02/2012 19:06:01</td>
        <td class="labelCenter">19/02/2012 11:09:01</td>    
                <td class="labelCenter">
                </td>
        <td class="labelRight">
                    0,00
        </td>
            <td class="labelRight">
                0,00
            </td>
        <td class="labelCenter">Value</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

My first approach used variations of,

```
$browser.table(:class, 'simple').rows[1..-1].each do |row|
```

but I'm facing a roadblock.

Also, why does not this work?

```
$browser.tr(:class => /odd|even/) do |row|
  puts row(:index => 0).text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could probably be made faster by sorting the collection first or something, or maybe extracting all the values into arrays and using some array functions to find the matching rows.  I'm sure there is room to make this more elegant

start with the first row, compare to every row below it,
move to next row, repeat

```
rows = $browser.table(:class, 'simple').rows
last = rows.length -1
last.times do |current|
  remaining = last - current
  remaining.times do |j|
    if rows[current].cell.text == rows[j+1].cell.text
      if rows[current].cell(:index => 3).text == rows[j+1].cell(:index => 3).text
        #do something
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Dank u Chuck.
Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$browser.table.trs(:class => /odd|even/).each do |tr|
  puts tr.td(:index => 0).text
end
```

Comment: Thanks p0deje, that makes sense, but that's only the initial part of the solution.
The main goal is to compare the mentioned fields.